# Debugging PostScript in VSCode/GhostScript

Tags: visual-studio-code, ghostscript, postscript

Has anyone attempted to set up the ability to step through PostScript using VSCode and GhostScript? I know you won't see the image until you display or close, but to check variables, dictionaries and the stack would be a great tool.

Comment: I don't know anything about interfacing with VSCode, but you can single step through PS code using my [debug.ps](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/debug.ps).